# WordPress Plugin for Custom forms with Admin Dashboard for sorting and exporting

Tags: wordpress

Is there a WordPress plugin that not only has the ability to create Custom Forms, but with the ability to have a full Admin Dashboard to manage the form submissions, as in sort, filter, export, etc.

Basically, something like NinjaForms, but with a robust Admin Dashboard and submission management system. The NinjaForms unfortunately seems limited (no sorting by fields, etc.) and I don't see a plugin to add onto it:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ninja-forms/

Perhaps, there is a plugin that can be customized to have what is need specifically?

I just need a couple of small custom forms and the admin dashboard only needs about a few fields to sort by per form and the export should export to Excel or CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research, looks like Formidable Forms has the specific custom Reports, Graphs and Statistics features I've been looking for, as well as providing tools to build custom forms:
https://formidablepro.com/knowledgebase/add-field-totals-and-statistics/

I haven't seen reporting features like this in other plugins like NinjaForms, Gravity Forms, Contact Form 7, etc... If there are reporting features in something else that match Formidable Forms, please let me know.

Thanks!